# angular interceptor check response data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-http-interceptors

I am very new to the angularjs, basically i want to check all $http request with angularjs interceptor and if the response data match 401 then redirect to login page

Any help appreciated

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @vinagreti Sorry about that ... It is angular version 1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find more details on interceptors [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

In short, you can put following code in config section of your main module.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    response: function(response){
      return promise.then(
        function success(response) {
        return response;
      },
      function error(response) {
        if(response.status === 401){
          //your redirection code goes here 
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else{
          return $q.reject(response); 
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```